# php random generate id like a32-jn3-sdf3

Tags: php

with the current code i'm getting are in5v6wyio0er5isu9rv4, so how do i get more number and less alphabets in the id?

below is the code which i have done

```
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $randomString = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }

    echo $randomString;
```

i would like to get the id in this format 6437270e-c2d4-4524-8a26-ad311c4ca55e.

Comment: Can you provide a few valid output strings, so that we can better understand what you do want and what you don't want?  What is determining where the hyphens go?  Do you want a maximum of one or two letters between each string of numbers?  Right now, your question isn't clear about what is a favorable result and consequently you will receive low quality answers based on assumptions.  Help us to help you.

Comment: Do you want uuids? There are libraries for that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

Answer (score 0):

If you want more number, get them higher priority by duplicate them in available strings:

`$characters = '012345678901234567890123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';`

And the number format, just pre-format them by yourself:

```
 $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $randomString = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < 24; $i++) {
         if($i % 5 == 0){
             // Add "-" each 5 characters
             $randomString .= "-";
         }else{
             $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
         }  


    }


    echo $randomString;
```

Comment: btw, is it reliable?

Comment: @ashura91 What do you mean by "reliable"? It answers the question correctly and will always get what the OP asked for.

Comment: @ashura91: What do you mean "reliable" here? I just answer the question with the key, the questioner has to edit it by himself to meet his requirement

Comment: It's a great answer. I'm just wondering if I use this method to generate many random id (possibly millions) whether it will still display the desired string format

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the for-loop. You're telling PHP to add a random character from `$characters` 20 times, so it will never print something like XXXX-XXXX-XXX etc. because the "-" character is not even in `$characters`. I see two possible answers:

1. *Add conditionals*:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
  if (i === 8) { // at the 9th position, add an "-"
    $randomString .= "-";
  }
  else {
  $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
  }
}
```

Do this for all `"-"` that you want to insert.

2. *Separate your for-loops*. That is, make first a for-loop for the first sequence of character, then add "-", then a second for-loop for the second sequence of characters, and so on. (at its face, this seems to be bad coding practice; the egregious [WET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) approach)

---

As for the wish to include more numbers than letters, make two different strings: `$numbers = '0123456789'; $letters = 'abcd...'` , or simply start your random number from `$characters` after the numbers (that is, `rand(10, strlen($characters) - 1)`) to get a letter or end it before `10` to get a number, if you want letters in certain places of the `$randomString` and numbers in others.

If you want to increase the odds of getting a number, use Huy Trịnh's brilliant suggestion: you can add more numbers or characters to `$characters` to increase the odds of getting a random character/number.

Answer (score 0):

Do some edit base on your code,and that' my noob way

```
$characters ='012345678901234567890123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
$randomString = '';

$count = strlen($characters);

for ($i = 0; $i < 32; $i++) {
    $random = rand(0, $count - 1);
    if($i == 8 || $i == 13 || $i == 17 || $i == 21){
        $randomString .= "-";
    }
    $randomString .= $characters[$random];
}

echo $randomString;
```

Comment: Great answer, but notice that your "if" condition carries with it a problem: when it evaluates to "true", the code will add 2 characters to `$randomString`. This might defeat the purpose of stating the condition `$i < 32` in the for-loop initialization. One could change it to `$i < strlen($randomString)` but I think this is overkill and very slightly more inneficient. Maybe you could add the rest of the code to an "else" block